# Why the MS filters (dropShadow, glow or shadow) doesn't work for <span> tags in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, shadow, dropshadow, css

I just want to apply text shadow to `<span>` elements in Internet Explorer 6-9. I'm using the following CSS code.

```
.dropShadow { filter: dropshadow(color=#ffff00,offX=5,offY=5); }
.glow       { filter: glow(color=#ff0000); }
.shadow     { filter: shadow(color=#00ff00); }
```

With this HTML:

```
<span class="dropShadow">span with dropShadow</span>
<p class="dropShadow">paragraph dropShadow</p>
<span class="glow">span with glow</span>
<p class="glow">paragraph with glow</p>
<span class="shadow">span with shadow</span>
<p class="shadow">paragraph with shadow</p>
```

The result is that only `<p>` elements will receive the *dropShadow*, *glow* and *shadow* styles. But `<span>` will not get styles applied. Why?

[There is a live example (jsfiddle). I have used IE9.](http://jsfiddle.net/k8rAj/3/)

Comment: I don't have IE9 handy but maybe they need layout? Try adding `zoom: 1` to the span's CSS definition

Comment: Thanks @Pekka, but triggering has:layout (using `zoom: 1`) doesn't do the trick.

Comment: @Pekka - haslayout does not exist in IE9 and disappeared in IE8.

Comment: @Rob ahh, good to know. About time. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add `display:inline-block` to your spans.

http://jsbin.com/ipiqak/edit#preview

Comment: This works! Thanks! Can you add more information to your answer then it will be of help for others.

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo, No, I took a shot in the dark and it worked. Sorry about that. :P

Comment: No problem, I appreciate your sincerity.

Comment: inline-block triggers the hasLayout mode. See here: http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html#prop